# Parse nested json string to string list

Tags: c#, json, list

I have following json

```
["a", ["amazon", "amazon.in", "aaj tak", "axis bank", "amar ujala", "amazon.com", "aadhar card", "airtel online recharge", "airtel", "axis bank internet banking", "amazon india", "air india"]]
```

Now I want to get it in list string

I tried

```
var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(result);


Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject obje = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(result);
```

And many other options but nothing worked, it throwing error.

Additional information:

```
Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

Comment: try `var options = obj[1].ToList();` ? I think you're trying to access the first item as an array when it's a string....

Comment: This is throwing error @var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(result); line

Comment: oh right my bad, erm....

Comment: It's throwing an exception because the root container is not an object it's an array.  You want to use `JToken.Parse()`.

Comment: @dbc Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have a JSON **array** while trying to parse is as a JSON **object**.

Replace

```
var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(result);
```

to

```
var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(result);
```